# How to speed up searching/Filtering in python dataframe formed using .txt files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, python-import

I have multiple .txt files. I have imported and combined them to form a python data frame by using

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

np_array_list = []
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_table(file, index_col = None, header = 0)
    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())

comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)
big_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)
```

It takes ~ 19 sec to to import  around 20 files and form a data frame. Is there a faster way to do that?

Secondly, 
Once the data frame is formed, It contains ~ 8 million rows. I need to filter rows using a criteria for values in 5th column

" values whose length is 12 AND they start with '26' "

I am achieving that by the following code.

```
big_frame.columns = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]

big_frame['Five'] = big_frame['Five'].astype('str')

mask = (big_frame['Five'].str.len() == 12) & (big_frame['Five'].str.startswith('26'))

big_frame = big_frame.loc[mask]
```

It takes FOREVER to filter out all the values that match my criteria. I've verified the code with only one .txt file. It does all the processing in ~ 3 sec.

But I need to process all files as fast as possible. Any better way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is first filter and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together, but performance depends of real data:

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

dfs = []
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col = None, header = 0)
    df.columns = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
    mask = (df['Five'].str.len() == 12) & (df['Five'].str.startswith('26'))
    dfs.append(df[mask])

big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot.

Comment: Computation time is now reduced to ~ 1 min. I believe that's fair, it works for me. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!

Answer (score 0):

On the building up of the Dataframe, you seem to be creating dataframes then converting to matrices then back... See if it's faster maybe to use pandas dataframe.append function (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

On the second topic - does it help if you create a len column and a first two char column and then filter that? Also is one condition much stronger than the other? It sounds like a memory management problem more than a computation issue.